# recompile invalid objects in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

As part of a database build, we have some sql which recompiles all invalid objects in the DB.  This was working fine, but now we see the following error:

```
ORA-04047: object specified is incompatible with the flag specified
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 156
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DDL", line 157
ORA-06512: at line 51
```

Could it be something to do with the fact that we've just created a load of editioning views for edition-based redefinition?

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE

v_counter INTEGER := 1;

CURSOR cur_invalid_objects
IS
SELECT object_name,
       object_type
  FROM user_objects
 ---*** exclude VIEW and MATERIALIZED VIEW object types
  WHERE status = 'INVALID'
  and object_type NOT IN ('VIEW','MATERIALIZED VIEW');



FUNCTION get_total_invalid_objects
RETURN INTEGER
IS

 CURSOR get_total_invalid_objs_cur
 IS
 SELECT count(*)
   FROM user_objects
  ---*** exclude VIEW and MATERIALIZED VIEW object types
    WHERE status = 'INVALID'
   AND object_type NOT IN ('VIEW','MATERIALIZED VIEW');

 v_total INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
 OPEN get_total_invalid_objs_cur;
FETCH get_total_invalid_objs_cur 
 INTO v_total;
CLOSE get_total_invalid_objs_cur;

RETURN v_total;

END get_total_invalid_objects;  


BEGIN
WHILE get_total_invalid_objects > 0
LOOP
  IF v_counter <= 100 -- Failsafe: exit while loop if the objects cannot be recompiled after 100 tries
  THEN
     FOR cur_invalid_objects_rec IN cur_invalid_objects 
     LOOP
    EXIT WHEN cur_invalid_objects%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_ddl.alter_compile(cur_invalid_objects_rec.object_type,NULL,cur_invalid_objects_rec.object_name);
     END LOOP;
     v_counter := v_counter + 1;
  ELSE
     dbms_output.put_line('Unable to recompile objects to a status of: VALID.  Please investigate further.');
     EXIT; 
  END IF;

END LOOP;

END;
/
EXIT
/
```

I tried removing the exclusion clauses for VIEW, but I got the same error.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `dbms_utility.recompile_schema()`? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_util.htm#i1002332

Comment: If you have dba privs. then execute this on the db server in sqlplus `@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object types supported by `DBMS_DDL.ALTER_COMPILE` are  PROCEDURE, FUNCTION, PACKAGE, PACKAGE BODY and TRIGGER (see [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_ddl.htm#sthref2542)).

Maybe you have invalid synonyms. Try restricting your query to these types.

BTW, there's also `DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema` (as mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name)

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that the reason this script wasn't working was that one of the invalid objects was a TYPE object - which as you say is not supported by DBMS_DDL.ALTER_COMPILE.  I can change it to use DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema if it supports TYPE objects, otherwise restrict my query to the supported object types.  Although I think it also supports VIEWs and MATERIALIZED VIEWs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps also:
[UTL_RECOMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_recomp.htm)

Comment: requires SYSDBA privileges, which I don't have.